# Is it possible to implement back & forward buttons in Autodesk Platform Service?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Let's say, after I hide one part in 3D model, I would like to cancel(re-show) it by Cntrl + Z or by clicking back button. I would like to do it in any acton. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply delegate the event of keyboard down and call viewer.restoreState(previous state) or viewer.showAll()

The old blog might be helpful
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/02/view-and-data-api-tips-how-to-set-hotkeys-for-viewer.html